# SQL query to find the average time differences between two statuses

Tags: sql, analytics

I am trying to find the time between status changes for tickets. The statuses are A,B,C,D,E. I need to identify where the bottlenecks are in the system. The table looks something like this:

| ticket_no | created_at | current_status | next_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/2/2022 | A | B |
| 1 | 12/3/2022 | B | C |
| 1 | 12/3/2022 | C | B |
| 1 | 12/4/2022 | B | C |
| 1 | 12/4/2022 | C | E |
| 2 | 12/4/2022 | A | C |
| 2 | 12/5/2022 | C | D |
| 2 | 12/7/2022 | D | E |

As you can see for ticket 1, it cycled between statuses B and C before finally ending at E. I want to calculate the average time tickets take to move between specific statuses (say A->C, C->E). It’s a bit confusing because tickets can return to previous statuses and tickets don’t need to move through every status. There is an order to the statuses but you can return to a previous state.

Any ideas?

I’ve tried a bunch of things, like lagging (only looks at previous/next), or even pivoting with case statements and subtracting but it doesn't seem to work.

Again the ask is to find the time spent (on average) to go between 2 specific statuses, such as A->C or C->E

Here's my query so far. The idea is to pivot things and just subtract, but I'm really not sure this is gonna be valid

```
with pv_times as (
   select ticket_no,
   max(case when current_status='A' and next_status='B' then created_at else null end) as ab_time,
   max(case when current_status='A' and next_status='C' then created_at else null end) as ac_time
FROM statuses
GROUP BY 1
)
select * from pv_times

# subtract times to find diff...but is this even valid?
```

Answer (score 0):

> time spent to go between 2 specific statuses

Enumerate all such statuses.
This is the lower diagonal triangle of a 5 × 5 matrix.

Then do a JOIN (.merge) to aggregate all observed
transitions against that vector of possibilities,
.count()'ing the number of them we observed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but any idea how to even start something like that in sql?

Comment: Oh that's not a problem, I'll post that

Comment: Added my code so far...